# Veteran takes a correspondence school lesson. Letters come from an alien who needs an Earthling to repair his ship. Final surprise is it's a "she"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a story about a (WW2?) veteran who takes a correspondence school where he is taught extremely advanced things. The lesson letters come from an alien shipwrecked on Earth who needs an Earthling to repair his ship. The final confrontation takes place with the surprise that the super telepathic alien is a "female" and they leave together in space as a couple.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: "A couple" of sorts, I guess. As I recall it, the alien is a mind parasite who takes up residence in the main character's brain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is "Correspondence Course" by Raymond F. Jones.  It's a point-by-point match.  The whole story is presently available on [Prospero’s Isle](https://www.prosperosisle.org/spip.php?article871).  It was published in the April 1945 issue of *Astounding Science Fiction*.